# why context.Context signal affects new goroutine?

Tags: go

I'm using `context.Context` to control multiple goroutines. A goroutine listens `context.Done()`, then print now date string. And the process listens `syscall.SIGHUP` which cancel context and then create new goroutine with context created before.

I think when `syscall.SIGHUP` emitting, the process will print one date string, however got two.

This process is running on `ubuntu18.04`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go printDate(ctx)

    sg := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(sg, syscall.SIGHUP)

    for {
        select {
        case <-sg:
            cancel()
            go printDate(ctx)
        }
    }
}

func printDate(ctx context.Context) {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
2019-01-02 01:02:03
```

but actual output is:

```
2019-01-02 01:02:03
2019-01-02 01:02:03
```

Comment: After reading context source code, I think the reason is that ctx.Done channel close after the second goroutine executes. So the process prints two date string.

Comment: The first go routine fires and waits for cancellation. Once the signal is received, two things happen; the waiting go routine prints the time and a new one is created which also prints since the context was already cancelled. I don't see why you would expect only one time print.

Comment: Before, i think `ctx.Done`, which returns a channel, will cause that the first go routine which listens on it gets something. So, after calling `cancel()`, the ctx would emit `Done` signal with value, and the first go routine prints date string, meanwhile the value of `ctx.Done` would be set empty. Eventually, the second go routine cannot get signal from `ctx.Done` because the channel of  `ctx.Done` is empty, and the second go routine prints nothing.

Answer (score 2):

After `cancel()` your `ctx` is done and stays done forever. So when you call `go printDate(ctx)` a second time you call printDate with a done Context and the case can run becasue ctx.Done() returns a closed channel and you can receive from a closed channel.

Comment: It's my mistakes. After close channel, the go routines which listen on it would get default value from channel, not blocked.